# Selenium WebDriverWait failing when element is clickable

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have a WebDriverWait set up to wait for an element to be clickable. It works in other projects and for everything except this element, it's working in this project.

```
    def wait_for_element(self, id: str, wait) -> bool:
    if wait > 20:
        wait = 20
    try:
        return WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout=wait).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-automation-id='" + id + "']")))
    except TimeoutException:
        debug_print("Element could not be found or is not clickable: " + id)
        return False
```

This function is used in the following code, with the first four lines added for debugging:

```
    element = self.get_element(self.IDs['CHECKSELECT'] + '0')
    print(element.is_enabled())
    print(element.get_attribute('data-automation-id'))
    assert self.click_element(self.IDs['CHECKSELECT'] + '0')
    assert self.wait_for_element(self.IDs['CHECKSELECT'] + '0', 5)
```

The above code prints the following:

```
True
opt-chk-select-0
('Element could not be found or is not clickable:opt-chk-select-0',)
```

I also have this set up to take a screenshot on teardown, and the screenshot shows me that the element was clicked successfully. I'm struggling to understand why the element is telling me it is clickable, the data automation ID is exactly what I expect it to be, and the automation can successfully click it, yet waiting for it to be clickable, *after it has already been clicked*, is failing. Does anybody have any idea? I'm unable to provide more info than this, such as the website under test.

Comment: _element is telling me it is clickable_: How do you arrive to this conclusion? How is `click_element()` defined?

Comment: probably is because your element is behind another. Try clicking your element  using javascript = True

Comment: @EnriqueBet Any good reason for not trusting in the much powerful and proven `WebDriverWait`?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I know it is clickable through three separate methods:
1. Grabbing the element and printing its `is_enabled()` value, which outputs True
2. `click_element()` does not error or return False. I have a built in exception handling for `ElementClickInterceptedException`.
3. When I use `click_element()`, I can see the effects of the element being clicked and it shows up in the screenshot as well.

Comment: @EnriqueBet I am not encountering an issue with `ElementClickInterceptedException` when I click it. My only guess at this point is there's some difference between the logic for these two approaches that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @Cecilia I still don't get the reason for writing `wait_for_element()` which is achievable using a single line of code `WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout=wait).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "optimized_css")))`

Comment: @undetectedSelenium It has built in error handling and can be reused with far less syntax than copying that line in every place I want to wait for an element to appear. I  placed this line of code with the swapped out ID into my solution, and it behaved exactly the same as with `wait_for_element()`. This is also not relevant to the question being asked. The question is why is WebDriverWait failing to detect a clickable element that I've verified can be clicked by Selenium?

Comment: Isn't that the expected behavior, you clicked on the button, so does the click action performed on it and it must have got disabled, it will change its state but not the all the attributes of in the DOM.

Comment: @Dev The 5th line of code was standalone before debugging, and it was still failing. This button can also be clicked multiple times regardless of that.